# jQuery event is not called on single click rather gets called on double click

Tags: jquery

I am calling page `getUserAdDetails.aspx?PID=` inside a master page using jQuery.
 I have to generate the id for button dynamically ... Code below works fine but it does not work on single click rather i have to double click the button to load the external page.. I am new to jQuery so i find it difficult to find a solution. Please check my code and would appreciate if some one can fix it..

If i also try to fire the same even on a link rather than button then it does not work..
Please see the code below this will give you an idea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passPID(pid, psno) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#' + psno).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader-small.gif"/> Loading...');
            $('#' + pid).click(function () {
                    $('#' + psno).load("getUserAdDetails.aspx?PID=" + pid);
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<input id='<%# Eval("ProductIDGUID")%>'  type="button" value="View Details" onclick="passPID('<%# Eval("ProductIDGUID")%>', '<%# Eval("psno")%>' )" class="btncss" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the script to:

```
function passPID(pid, psno) {
    $('#' + psno)
        .html('<img src="images/ajax-loader-small.gif"/> Loading...')
        .load("getUserAdDetails.aspx?PID=" + pid);
}
```

It was working with double click, because when you were clicking the first time, inside your function you were attaching a `click` event listener to that element. Then, when you were clicking for the second time, this handler was being executed.

---

Here is a solution with `$.slideUp`  and `$.slideDown` animations:

```
function passPID(pid, psno) {
    var $psno = $('#' + psno);
    $psno.html('<img src="images/ajax-loader-small.gif"/> Loading...');
    $.get('getUserAdDetails.aspx?PID=' + pid, {} , function(html){
        $psno.slideUp(100, function(){
            $psno
                .html(html)
                .slideDown();
        })
    }, 'html');
}
```

Comment: You are my Hero. Thanks Shef... I would appreciate if you can tell me how i can animate this i mean  how  i can add .slow or .toggle functionality so that div with 'psno' slides down slowly. I tried but it didnot work with the following code........ 

`code`
function passPID(pid, psno) {
    $('#' + psno)
        .html('<img src="images/ajax-loader-small.gif"/> Loading...')
.slow(1000)
        .load("getUserAdDetails.aspx?PID=" + pid);
}
`code`

Comment: @Student: You can't do that with `$.load()`, you would have to use `$.get()`. I am posting a solution with `$.get()` and `$.slideDown()`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help unfortunately i the same code but it didn't work for me.. it does not show anything....

Comment: @Student [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/JWmHY/). Most probably your server side script is not handling the request or is not outputting any HTML.

Comment: Thanks Shef, You came to my rescue again.. your script is perfect it was me who was making a mistake... apologies for that.. It works fine. Thanks again..

Comment: @Student Great! I am glad I helped. Consider accepting this answer by clicking the empty tick below the vote count on the top left hand side of it. So, this question gets marked as solved, and others who will have the same issue will know the solution.